# LINQ to pngSQL issue when selecting whole row

Tags: sql, linq

I have a simple query: select the most recent row where the parentId is not null. I have formulated the query both in LINQ(lambda) and SQL. I am attempting to retrieve the most recent children. I will attempt to visualise the data I need.

Original Data:

```
-------------------------------
- Id - ParentId - CreatedDate -
-------------------------------
-  1 -          -  07/01/2013 -
-  2 -          -  07/01/2013 -
-  3 -          -  07/01/2013 -
-  4 -        1 -  07/02/2013 -
-  5 -        2 -  07/03/2013 -
-  6 -        2 -  07/04/2013 -
-  7 -        1 -  07/05/2013 -
-------------------------------
```

Data returned by query

```
-------------------------------
- Id - ParentId - CreatedDate -
-------------------------------
-  6 -        2 -  07/04/2013 -
-  7 -        1 -  07/05/2013 -
-------------------------------
```

Here is what I am currently trying:

SQL:

```
SELECT a."ParentId", MAX(a."CreatedDate")
FROM "myTable" AS a
WHERE a."ParentId" IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY a."ParentId"
```

LINQ(lambda):

```
var uniqueChildren = myTable.Where(a => a.ParentId != null)
        .GroupBy(a => a.ParentId)
        .Select(b => new { ParentId = b.Key, CreatedDate = b.Max(t => t.CreatedDate) });
```

This returns me a few rows that include the key (ParentId) and the created date. I would like for this to return the entire row instead of the two pieces of information. I have searched similar questions and found a possible solution:

```
var q = from n in table
        group n by n.ParentId into g
        select g.OrderByDescending(t=>t.CreatedDate).First();
```

This looks promising, so I run it against my PostgreSQL database and receive the following error from VisualStudio:

```
"The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead."
```

OK that message is pretty straight forward, let me try it like this:

```
var q = from n in table
        group n by n.ParentId into g
        select g.OrderByDescending(t=>t.CreatedDate).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now I get another error:

```
The method or operation is not implemented
```

I can't seem to catch a break here. I went ahead and hacked together a sloppy looking solution using commands I know I won't cause any issues:

```
var q2 =
    (from a in myTable
     join b in
         (myTable.Where(a => a.ParentId != null)
                 .GroupBy(a => a.ParentId)
                 .Select(b => new { 
                                     ParentId = b.Key, 
                                     CreatedDate = b.Max(t => t.CreatedDate) 
                                  }))
     on a.ParentId equals b.ParentId
     where a.CreatedDate == b.CreatedDate
     select a);
```

So that retrieves what I need, but I suspect that there is a more elegant way of accomplishing this task. What are some alternative ways to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The errors you are seeing are coming from your postgreSQL provider. It is up to the provider to implement the appropriate query expression parsing routines. Which provider are you using?

Comment: In that case, I suggest you open a bug at their site. http://pgfoundry.org/tracker/?atid=590&group_id=1000140&func=browse

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will definitely do that. I still would like to know of some possible alternatives in the mean time, though.

Comment: What happened to that bug in pgfoundry? any news?

Comment: @AnestisKivranoglou I still haven't found out. The temporary suggestions was to find a new way to query the data. If I receive an e-mail with new information I will post the response here.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this:

Order all records so the latest record comes first, and take the top one.

```
var q = (from a in myTable
         where a.ParentId != null
         orderby a.CreatedDate descending
         select a).Take(1).ToList();
```

Should generate SQL looking something like the following:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM MyTable a
WHERE a.CreatedDate IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY a.CreatedDate DESC
```

**Update**

Ahh, so you want the latest child of each group of related children. Then something like this should do the trick. I guess the `Take` method will work with your provider. Seems like `FirstOrDefault` has not been implemented, as you've already tried that.

```
var q =
    from t in myTable
    where t.ParentId != null
    group t by t.ParentId into grp
    select grp.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreatedDate).Take(1);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This query only returns a single row and doesn't take into account which child it is. I need to get a list of the most recent children. I will make an edit in the original post as I forgot to clarify the data.

Comment: With OrderByDescending, I receive the error: "The method or operation is not implemented." I am submitting a bug report to Npgsql per @JimWooley's advice.